# Can someone explain how i would open a file (containg a list of numbers) and then pass them though my selection sort algorithm?

Tags: c

So ive genertaed a list of random numbers (of varying size) that need to be sorted using selection sort, i have the selection sort algoruthm but im not sure how to open my file, read it and then pass it through my algorithm.
In my selection sort i have an array of number for temporary ue but they need to be replaced with the numbers from the file.
This is my selection sort code im using...

```
int main() {
   int arr[10]={6,12,0,18,11,99,55,45,34,2};
   int n=10;
   int i, j, pos, s;
   for (i = 0; i < (n - 1); i = i + 1) {
      pos = i;
      for (j = i + 1; j < n; j = j + 1) {
         if (arr[pos] > arr[j])
            pos = j;
      }
      if (pos != i) {
         s = arr[i];
         arr[i] = arr[pos];
         arr[pos] = s;
      }
   }
   for (i = 0; i < n; i = i + 1)
      printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: See/read [stdio](https://linux.die.net/man/3/stdio)

Comment: BTW `i = i + 1` could be wrote as `++i`

Comment: Also change `int arr[10] = ...` to `int arr[]` =- Let the compiler do the counting!

Comment: Yeh i knew that but i learned python before moving to c so the first way comes quicker to me, will fix them up later thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which reads the numbers from standard input. The first number in the input is the number of integers to read.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NEW_ARRAY(pointer, length) \
    { \
        (pointer) = malloc((size_t) (length) * sizeof (pointer)[0]); \
        if ((pointer) == NULL) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Allocating memory failed: %s\n", strerror(errno)); \
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE); \
        } \
    }

void Read(int **numbers, int *numbersLength)
{
    int count, i;

    count = scanf("%d", numbersLength);
    if ((count == 1) && (*numbersLength > 0)) {
        NEW_ARRAY(*numbers, *numbersLength);
        i = -1;
        do {
            i++;
            count = scanf("%d", &(*numbers)[i]);
        } while ((count == 1) && (i < *numbersLength - 1));
        if (count != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Expected %d numbers but got only %d\n", *numbersLength, i);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Number of integers should be a positive integer\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}


void Sort(int numbers[], int numbersLength)
{
    /*your sorting logic here*/
}


void Print(const int numbers[], int numbersLength)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < numbersLength; i++) {
        printf(" %d", numbers[i]);
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    int numbersLength;
    int *numbers;

    Read(&numbers, &numbersLength);
    Sort(numbers, numbersLength);
    Print(numbers, numbersLength);
    putchar('\n');
    free(numbers);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want fgetc and fopen: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html, https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html. If they have varying lengths you will probably also be looping until you read EOF, the end of file character. Hope this helps and good luck!